# Why does TS with --isolatedModules not allow export declarations of type even when they are aliased?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.8, type-only-import-export

TS doesn't allow the following when the --isolatedModules is true:

```
export { Thing } from "./thing";
```

it also doesn't allow variations like this:

```
import { Thing } from "./thing";
export { Thing };
```

TS 3.8 has [new syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-exports) to tell TS that an import or export is type-only, but we can't use it just yet.

The nicest workaround I know of is:

```
import { Thing as ThingType } from "./thing";
export type Thing = ThingType;
```

The above works because TS knows that the exported `Thing` is a type, since it's created via a type alias.

Why doesn't the below also work? TS seems to have enough information to know that `Thing` is type-only:

```
import { Thing as ThingType } from "./thing";
type Thing = ThingType;
export { Thing };
```

As a data point, [Babel's TS plugin has no problem](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQMaoKYGcvQCIaoA2AhlCTMBAHZwlYrra5QHFkVXUAqAnmBjgBfOADMoEEHABEMftlRRgYGNIBQcgY0w58hUuUo04AXm3M97Q1z4CA3GrVEM8EqbgBGAEwBmB2owAD0hYRHNdVn0OI2oAGjphfyCQ-FQaLHhRCAh3DzsgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=typescript&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.8.4&externalPlugins=) figuring out that `Thing` is a type in that example.

Since the [point of --isolatedModules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#isolatedModules) is to ensure that single-file transpilation is safe, it seems that goal can be achieved while allowing export declarations like in the last example above.

So is TS's behavior here a bug? If it's intentional, then what is the reason for it?